# What is the "mouseover" equivalent of the following?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, mouseover

The following code works but instead of clicking on the "Container" div section, I would like the function to be triggered by a `mouseover` event. What should I replace `.click` with below?

```
$('.container').click(function() {     
    $('.menuBar div').hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
$('.container').on('hover', function() {     
    $('.menuBar div').hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just replace [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) with [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)... you could have thought about it yourself:

```
$('.container').mouseover(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

```
$('.container').hover(function() {     
    $('.menuBar div').toggle();
});
```

If you don't want the div to be visible again when your mouse leaves `.container`, use `hide` instead of `toggle`.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually looking for mouseover:

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/